# the kivymd app freezes when adding a large number of widgets

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, freeze, kivymd

When I try to add add many widgets to MDList, the app freezes. Can I update gui after every widget I add? Is it possible to add widgets without freezing?

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
kv = '''
ScreenManager:
    id: screen_mng
    Screen:
        name: 'scr 1'
        Button_:
            screen_mng: screen_mng
            text: 'scr 2'
            on_release:
                screen_mng.current = 'scr 2'
    Screen_:
        list: container_
        name: 'scr 2'
        on_pre_enter: self.load_items()
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                id: container_'''

class Button_(MDRaisedButton):
    screenmanager = ObjectProperty()

class Screen_(Screen):
    list = ObjectProperty()

    def load_items(self):
        for i in range(100):
            item = OneLineIconListItem(text=str(i))
            self.list.add_widget(item)

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)

app = Test()
app.run()
```

If I use multithreading, nothing changes, the app still freezes

```
def load_items(self):
    Thread(target=self._load_items).start()

def _load_items(self):
    for i in range(100):
        item = OneLineIconListItem(text=str(i))
        self.list.add_widget(item)
```

Help please

Comment: The `RecycleView` is intended for just that situation, but I'm not sure how it would affect a kivyMD app.

Comment: It's working on my verions without any problem.I'm waiting about 5 sec if i change range to 1000. **Python==v3.6.9, KivyMD==0.104.2.dev0, Kivy==v1.11.1**

Comment: Use `RecycleView`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to everyone who commented on my question, I did everything I needed to do.

```
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty, StringProperty
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivymd.uix import Screen
from kivymd.uix.button import MDRaisedButton
from kivymd.uix.list import OneLineIconListItem
from kivy.uix.recycleview import RecycleView

kv = '''
<ListItem>:
    IconLeftWidget:
        icon: root.icon

<RV>:

    viewclass: 'ListItem'
    RecycleBoxLayout:
        default_size: None, dp(56)
        default_size_hint: 1, None
        size_hint_y: None
        height: self.minimum_height
        orientation: 'vertical'
<Screen_>:
    BoxLayout:
        Button_:
            text: 'update'
            on_release: rv.update()
        RV:
            id: rv


ScreenManager:
    id: screen_mng
    Screen:
        name: 'scr 1'
        Button_:
            screen_mng: screen_mng
            text: 'scr 2'
            on_release:
                screen_mng.current = 'scr 2'
    Screen_:
        name: 'scr 2'

'''


class Button_(MDRaisedButton):
    screenmanager = ObjectProperty()

class RV(RecycleView):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(RV, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.update()

    def update(self):
        self.data = [{'type': i, 'arg': i**2, 'text': str(i + 1)} for i in range(100)]



class ListItem(OneLineIconListItem):
    icon = StringProperty()

    def __init__(self, type=None, arg=None, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)
        self.arg = arg
        self.type = type
        self.icon = self.__return_icon()

    def __return_icon(self):
        self.type = 'android'
        return 'android'


class Screen_(Screen):
    list = ObjectProperty()

    def load_items(self):
        self.list.update()

class Test(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        return Builder.load_string(kv)


app = Test()
app.run()
```